# Excel VBA - disable form before saving

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a simple spreadsheet in Excel 2010 containing a form that loads as the spreadsheet opens. The employee fills out the required form data and presses a "Save" button macro utilizing the SaveAs method.

My question is if it possible to disable the form in the saved copy? The reason is that I would like to avoid the form to load when our bookkeeping department opens the copy to review the data.

To clarify this is how my vba code is

```
Sub SaveAsButton()
Dim applicationUserName As String
Dim saveLocation As String
Dim fileName As String
Dim weekNo As String
Dim year As String

weekNo = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Service").Range("M4").Value
Debug.Print (weekNo)
year = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Service").Range("R4").Value
Debug.Print (year)
applicationUserName = Application.UserName
Debug.Print (applicationUserName)
saveLocation = "w:\Service Users\" & applicationUserName & "\Service\"
Debug.Print (saveLocation)
fileName = "Service" & "-" & weekNo & "-" & year & "-" & applicationUserName
Debug.Print (fileName)
fileName = Replace(fileName, " ", "")
Debug.Print (fileName)

ThisWorkbook.SaveAs (saveLocation & fileName)

End Sub
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need any code in the final workbook you could simply save as .xlsx and thereby remove all the vb components

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use `CustomProperties` for that.

First, create a `CustomProperty`:

```
ActiveWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties.Add "Saved", False, msoPropertyTypeNumber, 0
```

Change the value of the `CustomProperty` to `1` when user saves the form (add the following code to `SaveAsButton()`):

```
ActiveWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties("Saved").Value = 1
```

Add a check if `ActiveWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties("Saved").Value = 0` to the method which opens the form.

Comment: This also worked, although JosieP's solution was better in this specific scenario. Thanks for taking the time to explain!